# How to convert string to date in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can i convert time in string to date type?

Like

My string is "8:30am" while inserting this to my db(mongodb) it should be date type. How can i do this?

time.json

```
"time": {
        "type": "Date",
        "required": true
    }
```

component.ts

```
    var mydate = new Date('8:30am');
    console.log(mydate.toDateString()); -----> printing invalid date
```

I am doing project in angular2. how can i implement this.

Comment: Seems `new Date(...)` requires the date in ISO format like explained int he linked answer.

Comment: But my requirement is like this. How can i implement?

Comment: `8:30am` is no date. It's a time. You'll need to create an ISO date string from your `8:30am` yourself and then parse it to a date using `new Date(...)` or use some library that allows to parse all kinds of formats like yours.